# Nuxt is rejecting my custom Vue (vuecli) component library "Could not find a declaration file for module"

Tags: typescript, vue.js, webpack, vuejs2, nuxt.js

I built a small Vue component library with a VueCLI project I made using this tutorial:
https://javascript.plainenglish.io/how-to-create-test-bundle-vue-components-library-8c4828ab7b00

**Component Library**

The VueCLI project was setup with Typescript and thus is came with a couple `*.d.ts` files:

```
// shims-tsx.d.ts
import Vue, { VNode } from 'vue';

declare global {
  namespace JSX {
    interface Element extends VNode {}
    interface ElementClass extends Vue {}
    interface IntrinsicElements {
      [elem: string]: any
    }
  }
}

// shims-vue.d.ts
declare module '*.vue' {
  import Vue from 'vue';

  export default Vue;
}
```

my index.ts file is where I am exporting all my

```
import ATag from './components/ATag.vue';
import AnotherThing from './components/AnotherThing.vue';
...

export {
  ATag,
  AnotherThing,
  ...
};
```

and my package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "my-ui-components",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "vue-cli-service build --target lib --name my-ui-components ./src/index.ts",
  },
  "main": "./dist/my-ui-components.common.js",
  "files": [
    "dist/*"
  ]
}
```

The build script produces several JS files, a CSS file, and a folder for packaged images.

My Nuxt project is just a boilerplate project where I am importing the component library from our bit bucket account via ssh:

```
"dependencies": {
  "my-ui-components": "git+ssh://git@bitbucket.org:my-account/my-ui-components.git",
}
```

and wherever I attempt to import my components (downstream, in my Nuxt app) like this:

### pages/Index.vue

```
<script>
import { ATag, AnotherThing } from my-ui-components;
export default {
...
components: {
ATag,
}
...
}
</script>
```

I get this error:

Could not find a declaration file for module "my-ui-components" implicitly has an 'any' type

and "ATag.vue" isnt anything special really:

```
<template>
  <span :class="classes"><slot /></span>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import Vue from 'vue';

export default Vue.extend({
  name: 'a-tag',
  props: {
    type: {
      type: String,
      validator(value) {
        return ['is-primary', 'is-success', 'is-warning', 'is-danger'].includes(value);
      },
    },
    shade: {
      type: String,
      validator(value) {
        return ['is-light', 'is-normal'].includes(value);
      },
    },
    size: {
      type: String,
      default: 'is-normal',
      validator(value) {
        return ['is-normal', 'is-medium', 'is-large'].includes(value);
      },
    },
    rounded: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: false,
    },
    naked: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: false,
    },
  },
  computed: {
    classes() : object {
      return {
        tag: true,
        [`${this.type}`]: this.type,
        [`${this.shade}`]: this.shade,
        [`${this.size}`]: this.size,
        'is-rounded': this.rounded,
        'is-naked': this.naked,
      };
    },
  },
});
</script>
```

So what is it that I am missing? This will be my first type script experience so I dont know the ins and out of it all.

Im thinking that the upstream (ui-components library) declaration files are not being used in the build process or its Nuxt that has a problem with this.

Answer (score 0):

I assume it because of the way you export. Usually I write my export statement in an index.ts as follows

```js
export ATag from './components/ATag.vue';
export AnotherThing from './components/AnotherThing.vue';
```

Answer (score 0):

In the Nuxt project root add a declaration file named `my-ui-components.d.ts` with the following content:

```
declare module 'my-ui-components'
```

Comment: this fixed the error! But, it revealed another error: client.js?06a0:102 TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'call') 

I'll make another post for that.